# Why should I move to Prism 6?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have a WPF project using Prism 5, we are about to refactor a lot of code and now there is Prism 6 out there. I can see there are some breaking changes between Prism 5 and 6 but I can't find anywhere a comparison of `What's new on Prism 6` so I can decide for myself the advantages are worthy of the refactor or not.

So, the question is pretty straight forward: **What's new on Prism 6 and why should I care to update my code?**

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice set of release notes for Prism 6.0, 6.1 and 6.2 here:

- [Prism 6.0](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/wiki/Release-Notes---6.0.0)
- [Prism 6.1](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/wiki/Release-Notes---6.1.0)
- [Prism 6.2](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/wiki/Release-Notes-6.2.0)

I personally like the new `ViewModelLocator` and the `PubSubEvent` without payload...

Comment: searching through all the release notes wasn't something I was looking for, a "What's new" release would be a lot more welcome :/

Comment: well, all of the things in there are "new", whether it's an addition, removal or a change... you could look at https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism#moving-to-prism-6-from-previous-releases but that's more of "what do you have to do if you decide to update" rather than "what features do you get if you update".

Comment: Yeah, I meant a comparison with the old so I won't have to research how was the old way and how's the new way and compare it myself.